# Add items to ProtocolStringList

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I am trying to add items to a ProtocolStringList.When I use the add function no error is returned,however when I try to print the list I get null as values.
I dont't know what I'm doing wrong.I tried printing the size to but that also prints 0.I can't figure out what to do.Please Help.Thank you.
Here is the code:

```
public class demo {
    public  static  void main(String args[])
    {
        ProtocolStringList s=new ProtocolStringList() {
            @Override
            public List<ByteString> asByteStringList() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public int size() {
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isEmpty() {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean contains(Object o) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public Iterator<String> iterator() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public Object[] toArray() {
                return new Object[0];
            }

            @Override
            public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean add(String s) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean remove(Object o) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends String> c) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean addAll(int index, Collection<? extends String> c) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void clear() {

            }

            @Override
            public String get(int index) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public String set(int index, String element) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void add(int index, String element) {

            }

            @Override
            public String remove(int index) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public int indexOf(Object o) {
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public int lastIndexOf(Object o) {
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public ListIterator<String> listIterator() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public ListIterator<String> listIterator(int index) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public List<String> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
                return null;
            }
        };

        s.add("a");
        s.add("b");
        for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(s.get(i));//prints null
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to delete everything after `new ProtocolList()` and the next `};` and try again.

Comment: I removed it ,now I'm getting error ProtocolStringList is abstract cannot be instantiated.

Comment: I got it.Since its an interface I can't use new.Thanks @daniu for helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

`ProtocolStringList` is an Interface (like `List<E>`). You need to instantiate the implemented Data Structure to add elements or use its functionality.

Example

```
ProtocolStringList plist = new LazyStringArrayList();
plist.add("E");
```

Answer (score 0):

to add item to your your list in Java you need to use a Builder and build the object.

You have an example on the reference guide:
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial

```
  Person john =
  Person.newBuilder()
    .setId(1234)
    .setName("John Doe")
    .setEmail("jdoe@example.com")
    .addPhones(
      Person.PhoneNumber.newBuilder()
        .setNumber("555-4321")
        .setType(Person.PhoneType.HOME))
    .build();
```

In your example, your code should look something like:

```
 s = ProtocolStringList.newBuilder()
       .add("a")
       .add("b")
       .build();
```